Is pthread_mutex_lock() a syscall?
I'm trying to measure the system time and user time for pthread_mutex_lock(), and this is the function I came up:
void measure_mutex_lock_time(double *user_time, double *system_time) {
    pthread_mutex_t mutexes[NUM_ITERATIONS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++) {
        if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutexes[i], NULL) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_mutex_init failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    struct rusage start, end;
    double total_user_time = 0;
    double total_system_time = 0;

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &start);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexes[i]);
    }
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &end);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexes[i]);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexes[i]);
    }

    total_system_time = get_time_diff(start.ru_stime, end.ru_stime);
    total_user_time = get_time_diff(start.ru_utime, end.ru_utime);

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &start);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
    }
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &end);

    double total_user_time2 = get_time_diff(start.ru_utime, end.ru_utime);
    double total_system_time2 = get_time_diff(start.ru_stime, end.ru_stime);

    *user_time = (total_user_time - total_user_time2) / NUM_ITERATIONS;
    *system_time = (total_system_time - total_system_time2) / NUM_ITERATIONS;
}

The result is:
mutex user time: 0.000000e+00
mutex sys time: 1.100000e-08

This seems odd to me because I expect mutex_lock should not be a syscall. I expect the operation is entirely in user space.
Is there something wrong with my code or I just think it wrong?

POSIX doesn't have a notion of syscall. If you have a specific implementation in mind, you should mention it. Having said that, your expectation is unfounded. A pthreads call that needs to wait is unlikely to operate entirely in user space. Waiting this way is needlessly expensive

A minor observation is that the empty for loop could be optimized out by the compiler. I suggest using volatile int i in both for loops where the code is measuring time. Also, it would be useful to supply a [mcve] as we have no idea what get_time_diff does, or what the value of NUM_ITERATIONS is.

The times shown are too small to have a significant signal-to-noise ratio. How many times did you run the code, and did you get consistent results?

On Linux, you can run the executable with strace to trace the system calls. On Linux (with NPTL), there are no system calls between the getrusage calls.

For everyone's information, my iteration number is 1000, and get_time_diff just gets the time difference between start and end.

On modern Linux, mutexes are implemented with the futex mechanism.
A basic implementation would look like this:
while (!atomic_compare_and_swap(&lock, 0, 1)) {
    futex_wait(&lock, 0);
}

When the lock is not contended, acquiring it is an entirely user-space operation. When the lock is contended, the process is put to sleep and this involves a system call.

You mean the thread is put to sleep.

@IanAbbott: Yes, although on Linux, the distinction between threads and processes is a minor one. A thread is like a lightweight process that shares memory space with another thread.

True, they are all tasks in the Linux kernel, although the question is not about Linux.

The question was not tagged with any particular OS in mind, but Linux is a major and popular modern implementation of a Unix-like, mostly-POSIX OS. Its implementation could reveal an interesting insight that is very relevant to the asked question.

The answer does not provide any explanation for the observed user time and system time. It just explains what Linux does (although it does answer the question posed in the title, at least for Linux). On the face of it, all the locking would be expected to use only user time on Linux. OP's question does not indicate the number of iterations used in the test, so there might not be enough iterations to get a significant measurement.
